# How to get the values of a row in a table?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`abc.ejs`

```
<tbody>
  <% data.reverse() %>
    <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <td># <%= data[i].id %></td>
        <td><%= data[i].email_address %></td>
        <td><%= data[i].mobile_number %></td>
        <td><%= data[i].status %></td>
        <td><%= data[i].credit_limit %></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
```

Each row will have an `Edit` button and I would like to retrieve the values of that particular row when user clicks on it. How can I implement this in `NodeJS` ?

Comment: In nodeJs? Electron or something like that? Or do you mean in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use button click event

```
jQuery('.editBtn').on('click', function() {
    var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    var $columns = $row.find('td');

    $columns.addClass('row-highlight');
    var values = "";

    jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) {
        values =  item.innerHTML;
        alert(values);
    });
    console.log(values);
});
```

[Working Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/beME9/619/)